# SumAsync() with nvarchar value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, c#-4.0, linq-expressions

I have `tbl_purchase` table which has fields such as `order_date - DateTime`,`price - nvarchar`, `pid - int` etc., Requirement is to display total price with respect to each year in a chart. So to get the price, I decided to go with `SumAsync`. But the problem here is `price` field will be stored appended with `$` as in `$12,234.03`,`$4,453.23` etc., and as mentioned it is a `nvarchar` field. I Tried splitting the value within `SumAsync()` but was getting compilation error. Totally blank on how to work with this? Any work-around to split the `$` and sum up the values? Below is what I tried.

**ChartData.cs**

```
public class ChartData
{
   public string period {get;set;}
   public int purchase {get;set;}
   public string purchaseAmount {get;set;}
}
```

**Controller method**

```
var areaModel = new List<ChartData>();
var yearList = new string[]{'2015','2016'};
foreach (var year in yearList)
{
    int yr=Convert.ToInt32(year);
    var model = new ChartData
    {
         period = year,
         purchaseAmount=await context.tbl_purchases.Where(x=>x.order_date.Year == yr).SumAsync(x=>(long)x.price.Split('$')[1]); //shows complie error. Its expecting `long` but the conversion doesn't happen well here.
    };
    areaModel.Add(model);
}
```

Comment: Why is price stored as a `varchar` and not a `money` or `decimal`? that seems odd to me. Anyways, would something like the following should work `x => Convert.ToDecimal(Regex.Replace(x.price, "[^0-9.]", ""));` ?

Comment: @mituw16.. Let me try that once.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if price format is computed and always the same you can do as follow to calculate the price:

```
 var price = new List<string> { "$4,000.99","$20.99","$40,000.88"};

var sum = price.AsEnumerAble().Sum(x => double.Parse(x.Replace("$", "0")));
```

I just replace the `$` with `0` and calculate the sum.

Comment: I'll give a try and let you know.. :)

Comment: Throws runtime exception - `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Comment: you need to use `.AsEnumerable()` before the Sum.

Comment: Bdw I've mentioned that am using `SumAsync`, in which case above query would not work..

Comment: use `.ToListAsync()` intead of `.AsEnumerable`

Comment: Nope buddy, it doesn't `ToListAsync` at all for `price` variable.. :(

Comment: `context.tbl_purchases.Where(x=>x.order_date.Year == yr).ToListAsync()` you need to call ToListAsync before Sum!

Comment: Appreciate your effort buddy, but stil getting error.. `List<tbl_purchase> does not contain definition for SumAsync`, when `ToListAsync` or `AsEnumerable`  is used..

Comment: Works good with `.Sum`, but not `SumAsync`, because when we do `context.tbl_purchases.Where(x=>x.order_date.Year == yr).ToListAsync()`, it returns `List<tbl_purchase>` which will not have definition for `SumAsync`.. How would we overcome this?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Why is it so important to use SumAsync?

Comment: @Speedbird186 because the above piece of query is inside `async Task<JsonResult>` Action..

Comment: That doesn't mean every method you call has to be Async though. Your ToListAsync call is going to be the most expensive presumably, so running that Sum won't be a big blocking call.

Comment: So, for any `async Task<ActionResult>` one `await` is sufficient for it to work as expected..? @Speedbird186

Comment: @GuruprasadRao What exactly do you mean by "work as expected?" You are using Async so that your main thread isn't blocked by a lengthy call (such as a DB call). If the DB call is indeed the lengthy, resource-intensive operation and the Sum is just a quick addition of a few numbers, I doubt you'd really be able to measure any block on your main thread. (Remember setting up an async call has some overhead too... For a simple set of additions that overhead probably isn't justified.)